# How to perform a function if user hangs up in python Twilio IVR?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I want to save a callers information if an individual hangs up on the python IVR system.

ex:

```py
@app.route('/ivr/welcome', methods=['POST'])
def welcome():
    caller = request.form['From']
    response = VoiceResponse()
    with response.gather(
        num_digits=1, action=url_for('menu'), method="POST"
    ) as g:
        g.say(message=f"")

    # The functionality I want:
    if caller.hangs_up:
         hangup = HangUp(phone_number=caller)
         db.session.add(hangup)
         db.session.commit()
    return twiml(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the caller hangs-up, TwiML processing ends, you will need to use a statusCallback URL on the Twilio phone number to capture this `completed` event, and determine if they completed the IVR navigation or just hung up in the middle of it.

[image]